# Bash script adding special characters to the end of any file I create

Tags: linux, bash

I am creating a bash script to create backups, however the bash scripts mkdir is naming the folder with some sort of special characters on the end. if I ls the directory the name show up with a ? on the end which I know is terminals way of showing unrecognized special characters.

How do I get my bash script to to create the folder without adding on this special unrecognized character to the end.

Any help is appreciated.

See script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p "/var/backups/Backup"
mysqldump -u user1 -ptest DB tbl1 > "/var/backups/Backup/tbl1.sql"
DAY=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
zip -r /var/backups/bkup-$DAY.zip /var/backups/Backup
```

cat -A shows the following:

```
#!/bin/bash^M$
mkdir -p "/var/backups/Backup"^M$
mysqldump -u user1 -ptest DB tbl1 > "/var/backups/Backup/tbl1.sql"^M$
DAY=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)^M$
zip -r /var/backups/bkup-$DAY.zip /var/backups/Backup
```

Comment: If you are using `bash`, your shbang should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: What does `cat -A your_shell_script` show? If that shows special characters trying running `dos2unix your_shell_script`

Comment: I have changed that but it has not fixed the issue.

Comment: BroSlow, please see my edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cywgin not running script correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881493/cywgin-not-running-script-correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `^M` (`CR`) characters in your `cat -A` output are the problem: the shell treats only `LF` as the "end of line" marker, and the preceding `CR` character becomes part of the previous word.  only '/' and '\0' characters are forbidden in pathnames in POSIX(ish) systems.

you can fix your script with `dos2unix` or with

```
vim yourfile.sh
:set ff=unix
:wq
```