# mkdir in the bash script adds garbled chars in the folder name

Tags: bash

The folder created using the bash script (https://github.com/xatkit-bot-platform/xatkit/blob/master/build.sh) contains garbled chars. This is how it looks when I do "ls" in the directory that contains the created folder

''$'\001''x'$'\001''a'$'\001''t'$'\001''k'$'\001''i'$'\001''t'$'\001''-'$'\001''r'$'\001''e'$'\001''a'$'\001''c'$'\001''t'$'\001''-'$'\001''p'$'\001''l'$'\001''a'$'\001''t'$'\001''f'$'\001''o'$'\001''r'$'\001''m'/

I changed the line endings to unix-style (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980432/1364595), but that didn't help.

Result of cat -A.

```
build_platform() {$
^Iplatform=$1$
^Iplatform_name=${platform%"-platform"}$
^Iecho "Platform name: $platform_name"$
^Icd $XATKIT_DEV/platforms/$platform$
^Iecho "Building $platform"$
^Iif [ $skip_mvn = false ]$
^Ithen$
^I^Imvn clean install $mvn_options$
^Ifi$
^Imvn_result=$?$
^Iif [ $build_product = true ]$
^Ithen$
^I^Iecho "Copying created artifacts"$
^I^I# The directory has been deleted in the clean phase$
^I^Iecho "target folder: $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform"$
^I^Imkdir -p $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform$
^I^Icp runtime/target/$platform_name-runtime*.jar $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform$
^I^Iunzip platform/target/$platform_name-platform*.zip -d $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform$
^Ifi$
}$
$
```

Result of cat -v

```
build_platform() {
        platform=$1
        platform_name=${platform%"-platform"}
        echo "Platform name: $platform_name"
        cd $XATKIT_DEV/platforms/$platform
        echo "Building $platform"
        if [ $skip_mvn = false ]
        then
                mvn clean install $mvn_options
        fi
        mvn_result=$?
        if [ $build_product = true ]
        then
                echo "Copying created artifacts"
                # The directory has been deleted in the clean phase
                echo "target folder: $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform"
                mkdir -p $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform
                cp runtime/target/$platform_name-runtime*.jar $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform
                unzip platform/target/$platform_name-platform*.zip -d $XATKIT_DEV/build/plugins/platforms/$platform
        fi
}
```

Value of IFS - ' \t\n'. Not sure what was the value before running the script.

XATKIT_DEV: Location where I have cloned the xatkit project (https://github.com/xatkit-bot-platform/xatkit)

Besides changing the line ending, what else can I do? Kindly suggest. Tx in advance.

Comment: `Here is the result of cat-A` could you post result of `cat -v`? What is the value of IFS before running the script? `I do "ls" in the directory` Into which directory? What is the value of `XATKIT_DEV` variable before running the script?

Comment: @KamilCuk Tx for your prompt response. I have added more details to the description.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is in how you set `XATKIT_DEV`, not the code shown.

Comment: BTW, consider running your script with `bash -x yourscript`, or putting `set -x` early in it, to log each command it runs; that would have been an easier way to track down the exact point where the problem lives.

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate problem, btw, there are some quoting bugs in here; consider running the script through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds, so you don't have other bugs in the future when your directory names, platform names, or other values contain spaces or characters in IFS.

Comment: To be clear: `mkdir` is creating the directory you are asking it to. It appears the value of `XATKIT_DEV` is what contains the extraneous characters.